# Get radio button 's value

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm trying to create a quiz page with multiple questions on it. But now I fail to get the value from the radio button after the question is asked. I want to show the result to the user whether the answer is correct or not by checking the answers of that particular question.

Here is part of my code:

**JavaScript**
function question()
{

```
var questions = [];
var choices = [];
var answers = [];

questions[0] = " What type of seismic activity happens in an earthquake?";
choices[0] = new Array();
choices[0][0] = " shocks";
choices[0][1] = " rays";
choices[0][2] = " waves";
choices[0][3] = " bounces";
answers[0] = choices[0][2];

var rand = array[0];
document.getElementById('q1').innerHTML = questions[rand];
document.getElementById('1a').innerHTML = choices[rand][0];
document.getElementById('1b').innerHTML = choices[rand][1];
document.getElementById('1c').innerHTML = choices[rand][2];
document.getElementById('1d').innerHTML = choices[rand][3];

var ans = answers[rand];

function check() {
    var first = document.getElementsByName("fir");
    var firstvalue;
    for (i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        if (first[i].checked) {
            firstvalue = first[i].value;
        }
    }
    if (firstvalue == ans) {
        alert("You get the right answer!");
    } else alert("Your get the wrong answer!");

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name = "quiz">
    Question 1 :<label id = "q1"></label><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name = "fir">A) <label id="1a"></label><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name = "fir">B) <label id="1b"></label><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name = "fir">C) <label id="1c"></label><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name = "fir">D) <label id="1d"></label><br><br>
    <input type = "button" id = "submitbtn" value = "Submit" onClick = "check()">
</form>
```

Comment: Your radio buttons have no value. And what's `ans` in `if (firstvalue == ans)`?

Comment: Also, your labels are empty. You probably want to either move the `A)`, `B)`, etc. into the labels like `<input type="radio" name="fir"><label id="1a">A)</label>` or wrap it around the `input`: `<label id="1a"><input type="radio" name="fir">A)</label>`. If you do the first, you'll proabbly want to give your radio buttons an `id` attribute and put that id into the corresponding label's `for`: `<input type="radio" id="radioA" name="fir"><label id="1a" for="radioA">A)</label>`

Comment: I have add some more details about the code. I am trying to get the value of the question and answer from an array. How can I pass the value to the radio and generate a result from the whole quiz? Thanks.